# Storekit 2 Test valid subscriptions at launch

Tags: swift, combine, storekit, ios15

I have a new iOS App with an auto renewing subscription feature.
I'm using the Mercato lightweight Storekit2 library.
I issue a start to the transaction listener in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunch along with a retrieveProducts(), activeSubscriptions(), and activeSubscriptionsIDs().

It all works, BUT: the validation of an active subscription does not asynchronously complete until well after the initial viewWillAppear().
Therefore it always starts off in non-valid display mode, and premium features are available to select by the time the user starts navigating.

Is there a faster way to get a validation upfront, or failing that, is there a way to post an event that a subscription test has completed, so I can display, then stop some sort of distracting, time wasting animation until validation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

1. You can store locally the subscription status
2. During load time rely on the local information you have on the subscription
3. If validation fails eventually, turn off the subscription - but assume the user is good and give him a good experience